# How can I find all starred questions and order them by number of stars

Tags: feature-request

I read the [r](/questions/tagged/r) questions and answers.
I am trying to learn R and SO is a good source.

I would find it useful, to find all the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) topics which were favourited by a lot of users.

Is there a way to search

> [r] isfavorinted:1 orderby:#_of_stars

Comment: Be warned "favourting" doesn't necessary mean the content is good. People might bookmark for all sorts of reasons - to post an answer later, to check to see if the question's been improved, to remember to go back and down-vote tomorrow as they've run out of votes for today, and so on

Comment: all answers did not introduce that SO has some query interface. and ti is called .SE  and all answers use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59981/favourite-by-tag) - insert any tag (for example, [r](/questions/tagged/r)) and enjoy!

```
-- Get the ID of the tag:
DECLARE @tagName NVARCHAR(25) = '##Tag##'
DECLARE @tagId INT = (SELECT TOP(1) Id From Tags WHERE TagName = @tagName)

-- Fetch the results:
SELECT TOP(50)
  'http://stackoverflow.com/q/' + CAST(Posts.Id AS VARCHAR) AS Url,
  Posts.* FROM Posts
  LEFT JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
  WHERE PostTags.TagId = @tagId
  ORDER BY Posts.FavoriteCount DESC;
```

Dang, someone beat me to it :(

Comment: nice query, but you missed a couple of opportunities to use some of the Data.SE features described in the Data.SE [faq](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq). If you use the `[Post Link]` alias you'll get a link automatically generated. This is nice if the user changes the query to point to something other than SO. Also if you named your input `##Tag:string##` you don't have to worry about the quotes. This is more important quotes might be in the input.

Comment: @ConradFrix: Yup, saw all of those in your answer :)

Comment: the query does not add 'gem' tag to the problem and more addresses my original question

Comment: @user984532: Put `gem` as the tag then...

Answer (score 3):

Although the data does get stale you can use a Data.SE query for this

Here's one I wrote for you [GEM Questions by FavoriteCount](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59982/gem-questions-by-favoritecountt)

Here's the SQL code for it

```
SELECT p.id [Post Link], 
       p.favoritecount 
FROM   posts p 
       INNER JOIN posttags pt 
         ON p.id = pt.postid 
       INNER JOIN tags t 
         ON pt.tagid = t.id 
WHERE  tagname = 'gem' 
       AND p.favoritecount > 0 
ORDER  BY p.favoritecount DESC
```

Here's a query that takes in a tag name as an input [Questions by FavoriteCount](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59983/questions-by-favoritecount)